# Problem trying to create a procedure to update employees salary in a specific category

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, procedure

I want to update the salary of Assistant enginner in employees database, without make a inner join of the table salaries, tittles, and employees. It that posible thanks?

I am trying this script.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS psegui3 //
CREATE PROCEDURE psegui3()
-- we update first Assitant Egineer
UPDATE salaries s
    SET s.salary = salaries + 500 
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT salaries.emp_no, titles.title FROM salaries)
    WHERE titles.title='Assistant Engineer' AND titles.to_date='9999-01-01' AND
salaries.to_date='9999-01-01')
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am learing at my own. thanks

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` clause has to be *before* `SET`. This has nothing to do with the procedure, it's just the syntax of `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems in the `UPDATE` query, not related to the procedure. It should be:

```
UPDATE salaries AS s
JOIN titles AS t ON s.emp_no = t.emp_no
SET s.salary = s.salary + 500
WHERE t.title = 'Assistant Engineer' AND t.to_date = '9999-01-01' AND s.to_date = '9999-01-01'
```

1. `JOIN` comes before `SET`.
2. You need a joining condition between the tables.
3. You don't need to join with a subquery.
4. If you do have a subquery, it needs to select from `titles`, not `salaries`. And in that case, it can't select `salaries.emp_no`.
5. When you assign an alias to a table you have to use the alias in the rest of the query, not the full table name.